# rails pass params or variable to multiple controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a dropdown that displays multiple "principals", when a user picks a principal and hits submit the form passes a principal id param to the controller action.

The issue is that I need that params value in multiple controllers.

my view

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 button-wrapper">
      <%= form_tag(principal_analytics_path, method: 'get', class: 'form-inline justify-content-center') do %>
        <%= select_tag 'prid', options_from_collection_for_select(Principal.all, :id, :name), :prompt => "Select Principal", class: "form-control wrapper-space" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-primary wrapper-space', :name => nil %>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to "Clear", principal_analytics_path, class: "text-danger" %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

controller action

once I get a selected principals "books" I then need a way of passing the @pri_books variable from one controller to another.  Or a way just to pass in the 'params[:prid]` to multiple controller actions.  I'm not sure how to go about doing this.  Maybe a function that passes the variable from one controller to another?

```
  # displays graphs about principals.
  def principal_analytics

    @months_back = 12

    if params[:prid].present?
      # takes a principals id as a parameter.  
      # @months_back will determine how many months are shown in the chart.
      @pri_books = Book.principal_books(params[:prid], @months_back)  
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js {}
      format.json { render json: {success: true}}
    end    
  end
```

Comment: why don't you just define the method inside the `ApplicationController`. This way, you can use it in every controllers which inherits it

Comment: @sovalina Sounds like it's data (e.g. from user selection) that needs to be persisted across requests. A method can get you what you want given the user selections, but doesn't give you a way of saving that information beyond a single request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a session variable, that's what they're there for...

```
session[:prid] = params[:prid]
```

You can even set up a method in your `ApplicationController` to give you the principal when you need it...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_principal
    principal.find_by(id: session[:prid])
  end
end
```

Now just use `current_principal` where you need it.  (It'll be `nil` if you haven't selected one yet)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data you get back from the controller to populate hidden form elements (`hidden_field`). These fields will submit their values as params/data just as any other form element to the form's action. Note: this is not secure and can be easily manipulated by users, so if that's a concern don't use this method.

Alternatively, you can store these data in Rails' [session](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session) variable. This session is maintained in the server and can be used to store data across multiple requests. Be aware that to do this right you should make sure to have a sensible method to expire or delete session data to avoid (1) keeping more data around than you need and (2) confusing user experience where they expected a new blank form but had data populated from many clicks ago.

Answer (score 0):

How I ended up getting it working was to make a class level variable `@@class_variable` and then just set that within a controller action that received the params which I could then use in other controller actions.

Not sure if this is the proper way to do this or not though but it works.

```
# class level variable outside of any action
 @@principals_books = nil

    # displays graphs about principals.
      def principal_analytics

        @months_back = 12

        if params[:prid].present?
          # takes a principals id as a parameter.  
          # @months_back will determine how many months are shown in the chart.
          @pri_books = Book.principal_books(params[:prid], @months_back) 

          # set the data from the local instance variable to the class variable
          @@principals_books = @pri_books 
        end

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html 
          format.js {}
          format.json { render json: {success: true}}
        end    
      end

    def another_action
      @local_variable = @@principals_books
      @local_variable.do_something
    end
```

Comment: This only works if only one user at a time is using your application!  When a second user comes on, things will go south.