# the foreign key is just passing to the new form not the create action (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> This is my controllers and routes
> I have a albums controller and a bands controler with their models, and I want to access the foreign key to pass it, but it told me bands is blank

````
    def show
        @album = Album.find_by(:id => params[:id])
        render :show
    end
    def new
        @band = Band.find_by(:id => params[:band_id])
        @albums = Album.new(:band_id => params[:band_id])
        render :new
    end
    def create
        @albums = Album.new(albums_params)

        if @albums.save
            flash[:success] = "Album created successfully"
            redirect_to album_path(@albums.id)
        else
            @band = @albums.band
            flash[:error] = @albums.errors.full_messages
            render :new
        end
    end
    def update
        render :edit
    end
    def edit
    end
    def destroy
    end

    private

    def albums_params
        params.require(:albums).permit(:name, :band_id, :live, :year)
    end
end```

  resources :bands do
    resources :albums, :only => :new
  end
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass Band relation like below.

```
def new
  @band = Band.find_by(:id => params[:band_id])
  @albums = Album.new(:band => @band)
  render :new
end
```

OR check your code. Can you find Band with correct id?

```
@band = Band.find_by(:id => params[:band_id])
```

AND check your Views
You must put someting like below

```
<%=form.hidden_field :band_id, value: @albums.band_id%>
```

OR

```
<%=form.hidden_field :band_id, value: @band.id %>
```

Comment: but when I check the params I don't see the band_id is passing as a strong paramter, I see just the normal stuff

Comment: {"authenticity_token"=>"E2xZGElCSJibwI_5YQ0ohqtYmwo4t0EQwqq57lpa35ZZ_tOv4Z2ym2BF6BDVrjYlHbs7LaW8vfPT77bDjqZwIA", "albums"=>{"name"=>"jjuby", "live"=>"f", "year"=>"1990"}, "controller"=>"albums", "action"=>"create"}

Comment: in this request , my intentions is to passing the band_id as a foreign key in the Albums model, but when I see the strong parameters of new action it give me the band_id, but not in the create action if you see what I mean

Comment: {"controller"=>"albums", "action"=>"new", "band_id"=>"10"}

Comment: you can see it passing to the new form but not in the create action for creating the album of that band_id

Comment: In create action, you are building new object with new parameters which does not contain band_id. So you should import band_id parameter to Album form in the view.

Comment: yeah, I think of it, but in my semester in app academy they tell me if you use a foreign key in the form , any attacker can edit it and change it from 450 to 880(secret agent lol) , but good try , thanks,

Comment: You can write private methods for this type of requirements.

Comment: Hey @hassantarif look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52952654/8763546 you can use sessions for this type requirements. But be careful! Sessions stored at user's computer by Rails on default configuration. However you can change it. 
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

Comment: Hey, @Sercan Tirnavali , I try to make an update action in the albums but when I click to the form and submit the update it tels me that I don't have an update action but I have, you can see what is the problem
Started PATCH "/albums/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-03-20 14:56:14 +0100

AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'update' could not be found for AlbumsController:

Started GET "/albums/5/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-03-20 14:56:14 +0100
Processing by AlbumsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}

Comment: this is the pastebin of the albums controller https://pastebin.com/PxZ4dJ7T

Comment: Sorry i cant open pastebin.com server is not responding. Check your controller file and make sure of you have update function in it.

Comment: non problem, I find the bug, thanks @Sercan Tirnavali